# При попытки выделить сообщение в textarea, происходит перетаскивание блока. React

Tags: reactjs, typescript

При попытки выделить сообщение в textarea, происходит перетаскивание блока. React.

Если я передаю в любой обработчик событий (ondown, onmousemove и п.т вместе или раздельно вешаю именно на обработчики которые схожи в контейнере onDrag) textarea и сразу же "гашу" обработчик при помощи preventDefault() и stoppropagation- это не работает.

sender.tsx:

в этом компоненте происходит основная логика для отправки сообщения. (здесь и происходит баг)

```
    return <OnDrag>
<div className="container-sending">
  <div>
    {store?.from?.length > 0 && store.from.map((id) => <div 
      key={id.msg}
      className="message_from btn"
      onClick={() => dispatch(deleteUserHandlerSender({msg: id.msg, thread: id.thread}))}
    > » {id.msg === 0 ? '№' + id.thread : id.msg}</div>)}
  </div>
  <div className="container-message">
  {store.from.length > 0 ? 
    <textarea className="container-textarea" onChange={textareaHamdler} ref={ref} value={store.message}/> 
    :
    <div className="container-error">Требуется отправитель</div>}
  </div>
  <div className="container-button">
    {store.from.length > 0 && 
    <button className="btn btn-sender"
      onClick={dataSend}
    >Отправить</button>}
  </div>
</div>
</OnDrag>
```

ondrag.tsx:

это компонент обертка в который я прокидываю нужные элементы для возможности перетаскивания их по экрану.

```
const dispatch = useDispatch();
const ref = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);
const [cursor, setCursor] = useState({x: 0, y: 0});
const [translate, setTranslate] = useState({ x: 0, y: window.pageYOffset});
const storeSender = useSelector((store: ReduxStore) => store.SENDER);
  
const handleDrag = (event: MouseEvent) => {
  
  if(ref && ref.current){

    const dialogWidth = ref.current.clientWidth;
    
    const x = Math.min(
      Math.max(0, event.pageX - cursor.x),
      window.innerWidth - dialogWidth - 20
    );
    const y = Math.min(
      Math.max(0, event.pageY - cursor.y),
      window.pageYOffset + window.innerWidth
    );
    setTranslate({
      x: x,
      y: y
    });

  }

};

const enableDragging = (event: MouseEvent) => {
  
  setCursor({

      x: event.pageX - translate.x,
      y: event.pageY - translate.y

  });

}

const drag = useDrag(ref, translate, {onDrag: handleDrag, onMouseDown: enableDragging });

useEffect(() => {},[drag, storeSender]);

return <div 
        ref={ref} 
        style={{ top: translate.y + "px", left: translate.x + "px" }}
        className="container-drag_element"
        >
    <div className="container-drag_carry">
      <span className="container-drag_close"
        onClick={() => dispatch(openHandlerSender(false))}
      >✕</span>
    </div>
    {props.children}
</div>
```

useDrag.tsx:

это хук отвечающий за логику перетаскивания блока (в данном случае, компоненте обертки ondrag)

```
 export const useDrag = (ref: React.MutableRefObject<HTMLDivElement | null>, deps:Position, options: IDrag) => {
  const {
    onMouseDown = () => {},
    onMouseUp = () => {},
    onMouseMove = () => {},
    onDrag = () => {}
  } = options;

  const [isDragging, setIsDragging] = useState(false);

  const handlePointerDown = (e:MouseEvent) => {

    setIsDragging(true);

    onMouseDown(e);

  }

  const handlePointerUp = (e:MouseEvent) => {

    setIsDragging(false);

    onMouseUp(e);

  }

  const handlePointerMove = (e:MouseEvent) => {
    onMouseMove(e);

    if (isDragging) return onDrag(e);
  }

  useEffect(() => {

      addEvent();

      return () => removeEvent();

  }, [deps, isDragging]);

  const addEvent = () => {

    const element = ref.current;

    if(element){

      element.addEventListener("mouseup", handlePointerUp);
      element.addEventListener("mouseleave", handlePointerUp);
      element.addEventListener("mousemove", handlePointerMove);
      element.addEventListener("mousedown", handlePointerDown);

    }
    
  }

  const removeEvent = () => {

    const element = ref.current;

    if(element){

      element.removeEventListener("mouseup", handlePointerUp);
      element.removeEventListener("mouseleave", handlePointerUp);
      element.removeEventListener("mousemove", handlePointerMove);
      element.removeEventListener("mousedown", handlePointerDown);

    }

  }

  return { isDragging }

}
```

Comment: Вам так вряд ли помогут. Выкладывйте ваш код тут по [этой инструкции](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12004/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2-%d0%a4%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b3%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b0-stack-snippet-%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-react-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4-%d1%81-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b4%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b6%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b9-jsx) или выложите свой код, куда-нибудь в открытый источник, где можно запускать React приложения, чтобы мы могли запустить и увидеть результаты

Comment: стилей не приведено, но подозреваю, что для целей "перетаскивания" `div` контейнера находится поверх `textarea` и любые действия с нажатой кнопкой мыши приводят к перетаскиванию